# How do I multiply a tensor by a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

So I have array `A` with shape `[32,60,60]` and array `B` with shape `[32,60]`. The first dimension is the batch size, so the first dimension is independent. What I want to do is a simple matrix by vector multiplication. So for each sample in `A` I want to multiply matrix of shape `[60,60]` with vector of shape `[60]`. Multiplying across the batch `A`*`B` should give me an array of shape `[32,60]`.

This should be simple but I'm doing something wrong:

```
>>> v = np.matmul(A,B)
ValueError: shapes (32,60,60) and (32,60) not aligned: 60 (dim 2) != 32 (dim 0)
```

This is for tensorflow, but a numpy answer may suffice if I can convert the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to `sum-reduce` the last axes from the two input arrays with that `matrix-multiplication`. So, with `np.einsum`, it would be -

```
np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',A,B)
```

For `tensorflow`, we can use [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum).

---

With [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), we need to extend `B` to `3D` by introducing a new axis at the last one. Thus, using `np.matmul` would get the second axis of `B's` extended version `sum-reduced` against the third one of `A`. The result would be `3D`. So, get the last singleton axis squeezed out with slicing or `np.squeeze`. Hence, the implementation would be -

```
np.matmul(A,B[...,None])[...,0]
```

We already have an existing [`tf.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) function there.

Comment: The tf.einsum works like a charm. I wasn't aware of einsum. Thanks!